# Ошибка при запуске тестов с помощью Maven

Tags: java

Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно для org.apache.maven.plugins указать version. А какую именно, напишите подробно пожалуйста?

Сама ошибка:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=52703:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.1.4 -DskipTests=true clean -Denvironment=environment test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for ru.autotest_selenium:Autotest_selenium_project:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 25, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Autotest_selenium_project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Autotest_selenium_project ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Autotest_selenium_project ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Autotest_selenium_project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Autotest_selenium_project ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Autotest_selenium_project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Autotest_selenium_project ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.271 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-11T00:58:40+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/200M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Pom файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.autotest_selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>Autotest_selenium_project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

Помогите пожалуйста, не знаю почему не запускается. Вот логи:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=50094:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.1.4 -DskipTests=true clean -Denvironment=environment test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Autotest_selenium_project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Autotest_selenium_project ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Autotest_selenium_project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Autotest_selenium_project ---
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Autotest_selenium_project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Autotest_selenium_project ---
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Autotest_selenium_project ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.107 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-11T11:47:17+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/142M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

Может еще что-то нужно добавить в файл?
Должен запуститься тест через maven, открыться браузер и выполнить тест, pom файл выглядит сейчас так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Task2Selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>Task2Selenium</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Edit Configuration:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Логи:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=50991:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.1.4 -DskipTests=true clean -Denvironment=application test
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Task2Selenium 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Task2Selenium ---
    [INFO] Deleting C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project\target
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Task2Selenium ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 0 resource
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ Task2Selenium ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [INFO] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project\target\classes
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Task2Selenium ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project\src\test\resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Task2Selenium ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\1\IdeaProjects\Autotest_selenium_project\target\test-classes
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Task2Selenium ---
    [INFO] Tests are skipped.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 6.848 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-12T13:26:20+07:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 18M/201M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Но у Вас по логу "BUILD SUCCESS", где ошибка, то?

Comment: У вас IDEA запускает Maven с параметром `-DskipTests=true`

Comment: Очевидно, либо `-DskipTests=false` либо вообще без этого параметра. Где поменять не знаю, но точно Maven не при чём, ищите причину в IDE.

Comment: Теперь тесты не запускает: Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Answer (score 0):

У вас только Warning отображаются. 
Можете попробовать добавить в POM файл над зависимостями:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties
```

Comment: добавил пропертис и все равно не запускается:

Comment: Alex Lip, проект у Вас собирается, об этом сообщается `BUILD SUCCESS`... а что не запускается ? уточните

Comment: Запускаю тест с помощью Maven настройка в configurations, command line: clean -Denvironment=application test.
При запуске в логах ошибка выше. А должен открыться браузер развернуться на весь экран и далее остальные действия, но этого не происходит. Что не так? Может еще какая-то информация нужна?